# How to do reduce math.max to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. I want to get the max out of the number attribute from the array:

```
[
  {number: 1000, name: "Josh"}, 
  {number: 2000, name: "Joker"}, 
  {number: 3000, name: "Batman"}
]
```

I'm using this solution but I keep getting `NAN`:

```
const max = arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a.number, b.number));
```

My goal is to get the max and then store it in a variable

```
const x = { number: 3000, name: "Batman"}
```

How would I achieve it with reduce? It seems like it is only working with array of numbers.

Comment: `Math.max` returns a number. After the first iteration, `a` is a number, not an object.

Comment: What result are you after? Just the maximum `number` or the object with the highest `number`? Also, are the any extra conditions to apply if the `number` is the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Done by simple reduce,

```js
var arr=[{"number":1000,"name":"Josh"},{"number":2000,"name":"Joker"},{"number":3000,"name":"Batman"}]
   
var x = arr.reduce((acc, i)=>(i.number > acc.number ? i : acc))

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

With [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you have to remember that the first argument passed to the callback is the *accumulator*. That is, the return value from the previous iteration.

`Math.max` returns a `Number` (or `NaN` if the operands cannot be compared numerically) so on the second iteration, you will be trying to compare the `number` property of a `Number` which won't work.

As an alternative to `reduce`, you might want to consider sorting the array. This could be beneficial if you want other properties like the smallest value.

```js
// smallest to largest, use "b.number - a.number" to reverse
arr.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number) 
arr[0] // smallest
arr[arr.length - 1] // largest
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.max` returns a number. After the first iteration, `a` is a number, not an object, so `a.number` returns `undefined`.

When you pass a second argument to `.reduce`, you can ensure that the accumulator is always a number. If you only want to get the max number, for completeness, here is another way to do that:

```
const max = arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b.number), -Infinity);
```

I'd still rather go with @ntgwsth solution for more flexibility.

Comment: I thought that's what the OP wants, but unclear from the question IMO.   Returning the object would certainly be more flexible, which is why I said I'd use another solution. I just wanted to provide this answer for completeness.

Comment: I figured that's what they were trying to illustrate with that `const x = ...`

Comment: Maybe. But the previous code example shows `const max = ... `. They are also only saying *"My goal is to get the max"*, not "to get the object with the maximum number value" ...  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea. Here's a solution that uses `reduce` and keeps tabs on the highest-ranking object in the array:

```js
var nameNum = [
    {number: 1000, name: "Josh"},
    {number: 2000, name: "Joker"},
    {number: 3000, name: "Batman"}
];
console.log(nameNum.reduce(function(max,current){return current.number>max.number?current:max;},{number:-Infinity, name:""}));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to use `Math.max()` as a part of the reduce callback, here is a sample:
You can create a mock hash map for your options, and use Math.max() to select the right one.
Also, Remember put an initial -Inf object for the very first comparison.

```
[
    {number: 1000, name: 'Josh'},
    {number: 2000, name: 'Joker'},
    {number: 3000, name: 'Batman'},
].reduce((max, current) => {
    return {
        [max.number]: max,
        [current.number]: current,
    }[Math.max(max.number, current.number)];
}, {number: -Infinity});
```